# Assigning an enum value to a parameter

Tags: c#, enums

I have an enum that looks like this:

```
public enum MyValues
{
   value1 = 1,
   value2 = 2,
   value3 = 3
}
```

I then make a call to an external web API and get a value of `value-1`

My internal method which is expecting an enum value looks like this:

```
public void MyMethod(MyValues value)
{
   // Do something...
}
```

My question is how do I pass an enum value based on what I receive externally? Clearly I need to do a comparison and determine what I've received but I'm not sure how to "assign" an enum value to a parameter. What would be the parameter's type?

```
var myEnumValue = // What does my assignment look like?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option:

```
var input = "value-1";

var myEnumValue = (MyValues)Enum.Parse(typeof(MyValues), input.Replace("-", ""));
```

Answer (score 2):

What about:

```
var myEnumValue = (MyValues)int.Parse(apiValue.Split('-')[1]);
```